# R Programming: MICE Package for Imputation But Library Error --> namespace ‘tibble’ but >= 3.0.0 is required

Tags: r, installation, package

I have successfully installed the 'mice' package inside my R Studio.  But when I try and run the `library(mice)` code, I get the following error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): namespace ‘tibble’ 2.1.3 is already loaded, but >= 3.0.0 is required
```

What can I do?

Comment: install.packages("tibble")

Comment: you need to update `tibble` to a newer version, the comment before me does the job.